# CSOM retrieve selected item to insert in another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-addin

This code retrieves the selected items from my list "Contatti". Now I want to add them in the list "SMSdaInviare". 
How can I do it? 
My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowselectedItems() {

        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                web = ctx.get_web();
         if (ctx != undefined && ctx != null) {
            var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
                        var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Contatti'); // Put your list name here        
            var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
                        var camlquerystr = '';
                      if(selectedItems.length > 0){
                        if(selectedItems.length == 1)
                        {
                            camlquerystr += '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>' + selectedItems

[0].id + '</Value></Eq></Where>';
                        }
                        else if(selectedItems.length == 2)
                        {
                            camlquerystr += '<Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>' + selectedItems

[0].id + '</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>' + selectedItems[1].id + '</Value></Eq></Or></Where>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        var i;
                        camlquerystr += '<Where>';
                        for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length - 1; i++) {
                               camlquerystr += '<Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>' + selectedItems[i].id + '</Value></Eq>';
                        }
                        camlquerystr += '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>' + selectedItems[i].id +'</Value></Eq>';
                        for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length - 1; i++) {
                               camlquerystr += '</Or>';
                        }
                        camlquerystr += '</Where>';
                        }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           alert('Please select your item');
                           retrun;
                       }
                        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query>' + camlquerystr + '</Query></View>');

                        this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
                        ctx.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, Title, Telefono)');
                        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
         }
       }



        function success() {


/* iNSERT */

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("SMSdaInviare");
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,
        function(){ /* List exists, grab the user's item if it exists */
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        var itemId = -1;
        while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext()){
            var item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            itemId = item.get_item("ID");
        }
        if(itemId == -1){ /* Create item in list */
            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var newItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
            newItem.set_item('Title',_spUserId);
            newItem.set_item('Telefono',numRight);
            newItem.update();
            clientContext.load(newItem);
        }else{ /* Update item in list */
            var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
            item.set_item('Telefono',numRight);
            item.update();
            clientContext.load(item);
        }
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync();
    }),Function.createDelegate(this,
        function(sender,args){ /* List doesn't exist. */
                alert(args.get_message());
    }));

/* FINE iNSERT */

    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') +
            '\nCell: ' + oListItem.get_item('Telefono');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
        }

        function failed(sender, args) {
            alert('failed. Message:' + args.get_message());
        }        
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ShowselectedItems();">Show Items</a>
```

Comment: Before asking others please spend some time with your code. The formatting is awful and there are easy to avoid code flaws like unused variables (for example `listId`).

Comment: Ok but can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference of below code to insert the list item. Using this you can repair your code.

**Code:**

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function createListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
    oListItem.set_item('Body', 'Hello World!');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

You can learn more from : [How to Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011%28v=office.14%29.aspx)